# Please explain the flow/output

Tags: java, static, runnable

Sorry for asking this basic question.
I was unable to understand the flow of this program.

```
public class ThreadTest {

    private static String msg = "HCL";

    static {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                msg = "Technologies";
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

}
```

And the output is

```
HCL
```

I tried to run in debug, But I was not able to understand. Can some one help me understand how the output has come?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you don't understand this simple code you might consider reading and studying some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your classic race condition: `main` prints the value before it gets changed by the thread started in the static initializer.

If you add a little wait and print `msg` again, you will see a different output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(msg);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

prints

```
HCL
Technologies
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Q5waQ9)